# How to split a string based on commas except inside parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that contains a create query, and I'm trying to split it based on commas.  Unfortunately, some of the lines have commas in them surrounded by parenthesis.

Example:

```
dbo.Display_Test1.Column,
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('XVR', Test3)  = 0 THEN LEFT(Test3, (CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) - 12)) ELSE Test3 END AS Test3,
dbo.Display_Test2.Column,
ISNULL((CASE WHEN [2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] > 0 AND  [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (([2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] * 1000) / [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber)  END), 0) AS Test6,
```

I want to split my string based on commas that aren't inside of (possibly multiple) parenthesis.  For reference, my example should be split where the line breaks are (although my string doesn't have the line breaks in it).

I've tried a number of different solutions, but none work quite right:

`/(?:\(*[^()]*\)|[^,])+/g` works on lines 1,3, and 4, but fails on line 2.  It breaks up the line into multiple matches.

`/((?:[^,(]+|(\((?:[^()]+)|$1\)))+)/g` works on lines 1,2, and 3, but fails on line 4.  It also breaks up the line into multiple matches.

I can't quite seem to make it work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [it sounds like you're asking about the wrong thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). *Why* are you trying to split up the query after it's been formed (after all, the information you want is available without weird string splitting before you form the query)? What information are you trying to extract?

Comment: It isn't possible with javascript regex.

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "__i have this__" and  "__I need this__".

Comment: That "possibly multiple" parenthesis makes your language non regular and not parseable with a regex.  Just use the proper parser for that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's a very narrow use case, and all I have is the query to go on.  It's not worth explaining the full problem.  It would just add clutter and confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution possible : *( note : we remove the separations comas )*

```js
var str = "dbo.Display_Test1.Column, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('XVR', Test3)  = 0 THEN LEFT(Test3, (CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) - 12)) ELSE Test3 END AS Test3, dbo.Display_Test2.Column, ISNULL((CASE WHEN [2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] > 0 AND  [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (([2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] * 1000) / [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber)  END), 0) AS Test6,";
// if the string don't end by a coma , we add it.
var strArr = str.replace(/,*\s*$/ , ',').split('');

var res;
res = strArr.reduce(function( trans , charValue ){ 

  if(charValue === '(') {
     trans.deep++;
  }
  
  if(charValue === ')') {
     trans.deep--;
  }
  
  if( trans.deep === 0){
    if(charValue===',') {
       trans.arr.push( trans.str);
       trans.str = '';
    }else{
       trans.str += charValue;
    }
    
  }else{
       trans.str += charValue;
    }
  return  trans;
  
}, { arr : [] , str : '' ,deep : 0});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res.arr , null , ' ') + '</pre>');
```

---

*Edit* :

- As suggested by ***Thriggle*** in the comments i've added the case where the string don't end by a coma.
- changed variables name .

Comment: Nice approach! However, the `looking` Boolean seems unnecessary; all that matters is the depth as measured by `deep`. This approach also doesn't handle cases where the input string does not end with a comma (in such cases it leaves off the final element).

Comment: @Thriggle yes sure ! the looking is there only for my test purpose and forgot / lazy  to remove it.**(it was late)** About the final comma i don't understand what you mean, if the string finish with a coma use it as it is else add it before starting. I just aswered to the question you ask, I just wanted to lead you to a way, i know i couldn't provide you the solution for all your use case. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course if we want to work with unlimited nesting of parentheses then it would be impossible to avoid a loop. Still for some bounded nesting we do can write a regular expression capturing it.

For up to 1 parentheses level it could be

```
/((?:[^(),]|\([^()]*\))+)/g
```

For up to 2 parentheses level (probably it's your case)

```
/((?:[^(),]|\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\))+)/g
```

And so on, recursively substituting `[^()]*` with `(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*`

Answer (score 0):

Regex won't get you where you want and still allow arbitrary complexity.

One approach is to iterate through each character in the string, keeping track of when you hit open and close parentheses, and only splitting on commas when the numbers of open and close parentheses cancel each other out (so you know you're not within a parenthetical statement).

```
function splitQuery(input){
  var arr = [];
  var lastStart = 0;
  var open = 0;
  for(var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++){
    var curr = input[i];
    if(curr === "("){open += 1;}
    else if(curr === ")"){ open = open < 1 ? 0 :open -=1;}
    else if(curr === ","){
      if(open === 0){
        arr.push(input.substring(lastStart,i));
        lastStart = i+1;
      }
    }else if(i+1 === len){
       arr.push(input.substring(lastStart,i+1));
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Just be aware that this approach can be expensive (from a performance perspective) when dealing with especially large strings.

Here's a working example:

```js
var query = "dbo.Display_Test1.Column, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('XVR', Test3)  = 0 THEN LEFT(Test3, (CHARINDEX(' To ', Test3) - 12)) ELSE Test3 END AS Test3, dbo.Display_Test2.Column, ISNULL((CASE WHEN [2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] > 0 AND  [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (([2-Display-Test4].[Total Number] * 1000) / [1-Display-Test5].SumOfNumber)  END), 0) AS Test6,";

var split = splitQuery(query);
var output = document.getElementById("output")
for(var el in split){
  output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",el + ": "+ split[el]+"<hr/>");
}

function splitQuery(input){
  var arr = [];
  var lastStart = 0;
  var open = 0;
  for(var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++){
    var curr = input[i];
    if(curr === "("){open += 1;}
    else if(curr === ")"){ open = open < 1 ? 0 :open -=1;}
    else if(curr === ","){
      if(open === 0){
        arr.push(input.substring(lastStart,i));
        lastStart = i+1;
      }
    }else if(i+1 === len){
       arr.push(input.substring(lastStart,i+1));
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```